# How does pinterest insert an iframe into a cross-domain site

Tags: iframe, cross-domain, bookmarklet

I recently installed Pinterest's 'pinit' bookmarklet from http://about.pinterest.com/goodies because I was interested to know how this works.

**My problem is ...**

I want to create similar functionality to allow scientists to take images they have added to things like Flickr, university websites etc. and be able to annotate them with metadata and have them all appear on a single page.

I noticed (through Firebug) that when the Pinterest pinit bookmarklet is clicked, it inserts an iframe into the DOM of the page that is being viewed. I was under the impression that this should not be allowed by browsers due to cross-domain concerns. Since it is, does anyone have any ideas/code snippets re: how can be done.

Comment: Useful info here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12291043/is-a-javascript-bookmarklet-that-can-set-domain-cookies-breaking-cross-domain-se?rq=1

Comment: It seems that the code coming from a bookmarklet is considered to be originating from the domain that is being viewed (since the user has to explictly install it). Hence this is just a matter of learning to create a bookmarklet that can manipulate the DOM. Will post results.